# Publish Google Sheet as a Web App bound to the Worksheets not other HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed a Google Sheets project with lots of Apps Script driving user experience, including accessing files on my Drive. The user is working with the Spreadsheet and its Sheets.

This should serve many users **accessing through the Internet (not necessarily having any Google account)**.

Publishing the project as a Web project open to "Anyone in the Internet" and using the published URL - it expects to be returned with an HTML from doGet(e).

However, **my user interface are the Sheets themselves!**

I'm almost sure it was the normal behavior in the past.

**How can I bind the Sheets as the user interface in that web application?**

What I tried to do, is to have an HTML auto call a script to open the Worksheet - but it doesn't trigger the script. Here it is:

```
function doGet(e) {

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("opensheet.html")
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

The HTML that should trigger the Spreadsheet to open:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body onLoad="getData ();">
    <p>Loading app. Please wait...</p>
    <script>
        function getData() {
            var sheetFileId = "1e07gJ1...VEJDqMbTI";
            var sheetFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetFileId);            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advice - how to get it to work?

Thanks!
Mor

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to bind your Google Sheets to your Web App and allow users to edit the Sheet.

I found this solution by [omarsden](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/133689-how-to-embed-an-editable-google-docs-sheet) and applied it in Web App.

Here are the steps:

1. In the spreadsheet you want to publish. Click the **Share** button, change it to **Anyone on the internet with this link can edit** and save the generated URL in your text editor or anywhere safe.
2. Go to **File** -> **Publish to the web** -> Click **Embed** tab -> Choose from "Entire Document" or the Sheet you want to publish -> Click Publish. This will generate a iframe html tag. Save it in your text editor.
3. In the html tag, replace `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/sheetID/pubhtml` (*Entire document*) or `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/sheetID/pubhtml?gid=0` (*specific Sheet*) with  with the link you save earlier.
4. In your `opensheet.html`, add the `<iframe>` you've edited inside the body of your html. It should be similar with the code provided below.
5. **Save** and **Redeploy** your Web App.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <iframe width="1000px" height="500px" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/Sheet ID/edit?usp=sharing?widget=true&amp;headers=false"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Built-in Google Services such as SpreadsheetApp can only be used in the server side of your app (.gs files). If you want to execute a server side command in your html, check [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

Comment: Hey Nikko. Thanks so much for sharing this option! It is coming up, but seems like scripts are not working. onOpen, onEdit didn't kick in, and a button bound script (that just inserts a value to a cell) started to run but failed. Any known obstacles with scripts?

Comment: @MorSagmon - For trigger, Use [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) since any event captured by Installable Trigger will be executed under the account created it. And unfortunately for buttons, the user needs to login and authorize the script which requires the user to open the sheet.

Comment: Thank Nikko. User login is what I must refrain from. I understand Google Sheets-based application cannot really replace a public, fully functional website...

Comment: Thanks Nikko. I had to drop Google Sheets for this project and write bare bones website instead...